# Windows CE 5.0 : Issue with Arabic Locale

Tags: c#, smart-device

I am developing smart device application using C#.net, 
And I have a problem writing Arabic text on labels and buttons and it seen in a reversed way

**Example**:

if `button.Text = "السجاد"`

when displaying this it show like this : `د ا ج س ل ا`

I searched the web to find a solution for this problem with no result yet. 
I hope any one help. Thanks In Advance

Comment: What GUI framework are you using?  Also, what IDE or other development tool are you using to write your code?

Comment: Looks as though your IDE supports displaying right-to-left string literals (Visual Studio does) but your GUI does not.  Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms917973.aspx.   More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906457.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906461.aspx.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2008 and can't find right-to-left property in the controls.

Comment: With windows desktop and VS 2008, there is no property in the controls.  Right-to-left text is rendered correctly automatically.  (I just tested it now.)  Windows CE 5.0 is 10 years old and no longer supported, so it may not work.  Try following the instructions in the link I posted above: [Creating a Complex Scripts-enabled Run-Time Image (Windows CE 5.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms917973.aspx)

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no property in desktop windows forms controls needed to make right-to-left *text* render correctly; it should just work.  To reflect the overall appearance of controls and forms, see here: [Bi-Directional Support for Windows Forms Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh376txk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).